# WordPress error on pllugin update: No support for ssh2 stream timeout. Please recompile with libssh2 >= 1.2.9

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, libssh2

I have installed the latest version of libssh2 on my Ubuntu machine in order to enable ssh2 and sftp plugin updates. Unfortunately I get this error:

```
No support for ssh2 stream timeout. Please recompile with libssh2 >= 1.2.9 
in mysite/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ssh2.php on line 134
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After hour of fruitless attempts to fix it I dug up this plugin that fixed the issue using alternative ssh library

**SSH SFTP Updater Support**

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/wordpress.htm

Comment: The version at http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/ might be newer idk.